# Magallanes - Deploy on Windows

Tags: windows, deployment

I am trying to deploy a project from PhpStorm (Windows) on a server but I have an error when I launch the command :

```
bin\mage deploy develop
```

My .mage.yml file :

```
magephp:
environments:
    develop:
        user: ******
        branch: develop
        from: ./
        host_path: /var/www/smart
        releases: 2
        exclude:
            - ./vendor
            - ./node_modules
            - .env
        hosts:
          - *******
        ssh:
           port: ******
           flags: -q -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
        pre-deploy:
        on-deploy:
        on-release:
        post-release:
        post-deploy:
        log_dir: /var/www/mage.log
```

When I launch the command I have the following error :

```
Starting Pre Deploy tasks:
    Running [Git] Change Branch (develop) ... FAIL
Finished 0/2 tasks for Pre Deploy.
```

I try to do a git checkout, and it works. 
I also try to remove the branch in .mage.yml file, but I have an other error :

```
Starting Pre Deploy tasks:
    Running [Deploy] Preparing Tar file ... FAIL
Finished 0/1 tasks for Pre Deploy.
```

Any idea ? 
Thanks in advance (and sorry for my bad english)

Comment: I use the Magallanes v3.3.0 Nostromo from https://www.magephp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found an answer by myself. I put it here, if some people want to use magallanes/mage-php to deploy from Windows.

This solution works only if you have Windows 10. You can install Ubuntu without a dual-boot, you just need to activate this Windows's feature:

```
Windows Subsystem for Linux
```

This tutorial explain how to do it :

https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/

Then you just have to execute your command from the bash console !

Comment: I can't seems to manage to deploy from windows, even with bash on ubuntu

Comment: Can you provide us more information about your problem ? Mage php is installed (bin/mage version to check) ?

Comment: Hello, I have opened a ticket on the GitHub:
https://github.com/andres-montanez/Magallanes/issues/437